# Oracle: does selecting username and current schema from v$session in a procedure change the result compared to running it as standalone statement

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, privileges

I am building a procedure, fired on a system login trigger, to record v$session information beyond the lifetime of the session. Most of the procedure works exactly as expected, but when I try and record the schemaname of the session that has just logged in (i.e. before any commands are executed by, or on it), it returns the schemaname of the location of the procedure, not the schemaname that is in v$session for the login schema. My code is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DB_AUDIT_LOGON (p_sessionid number)
IS
 
   v_sessionid       number;   
   v_sid             number;   
   v_serialno        number;   
   v_username        VARCHAR2 (128); 
   v_schemaname      VARCHAR2 (128); 
   v_osuser          VARCHAR2 (128); 
   v_machine         VARCHAR2 (64); 
   v_terminal        VARCHAR2 (30); 
   v_program         VARCHAR2 (48); 
   v_logon           DATE; 
   v_clientid        VARCHAR2 (64); 
   v_authid          VARCHAR2 (128); 
   v_authmethod      VARCHAR2 (128);
   v_curruser        VARCHAR2 (128);
   v_proxyuser       VARCHAR2 (128);
   v_authtyp         VARCHAR2 (26);
   v_clientdrv       VARCHAR2 (30);
   v_clientver       VARCHAR2 (40);
  
BEGIN

-- Collection of userenv session variables

v_sessionid := p_sessionid;
v_authid := sys_context('USERENV', 'AUTHENTICATED_IDENTITY');
v_authmethod := sys_context('USERENV', 'AUTHENTICATION_METHOD');
v_curruser := sys_context('USERENV', 'CURRENT_USER');
v_proxyuser := sys_context('USERENV', 'PROXY_USER');

-- Collection of all information from v$session

select 
    sid,
    serial#,
    username,
    schemaname,
    osuser,
    machine,
    terminal,
    program,
    logon_time,
    client_identifier
into 
    v_sid,
    v_serialno,
    v_username,
    v_schemaname,
    v_osuser,
    v_machine,
    v_terminal,
    v_program,
    v_logon,
    v_clientid
from v$session where audsid = v_sessionid;

-- Collection of v$session_connect_info variables

select
    unique(authentication_type)
into
    v_authtyp
from v$session_connect_info
where sid = v_sid and serial# = v_serialno;    
    
select    
    unique(client_driver)
into    
    v_clientdrv
from v$session_connect_info
where sid = v_sid and serial# = v_serialno;

select
    unique(client_version)
into
    v_clientver
from v$session_connect_info
where sid = v_sid and serial# = v_serialno;

-- Insertion of collected session information into 
-- DB_AUDIT_LOG

insert into DB_AUDIT_LOG
(
    sessionid,
    sid,
    serialno,
    username,
    schemaname,
    osuser,
    machine,
    terminal,
    program,
    logon_time,
    client_identifier,
    authenticated_identity,
    authentication_method,
    current_user,
    proxy_user,
    authentication_type,
    client_driver,
    client_version)
values
(
    v_sessionid,
    v_sid,
    v_serialno,
    v_username,
    v_schemaname,
    v_osuser,
    v_machine,
    v_terminal,
    v_program,
    v_logon,
    v_clientid,
    v_authid,
    v_authmethod,
    v_curruser,
    v_proxyuser,
    v_authtyp,
    v_clientdrv,
    v_clientver);

END;
/
```

I know I have a flaw in the code with the selection of sys_context('userenv','current_user') as this will default to the schema that the procedure is stored in, but don't understand why the schemaname in the session also does so.

I'm running Oracle 19C and the procedure is on SYS as I encountered a complex privilege issue when trying to grant select on the v_$session and v_$session_connect_info tables that the procedure references.

So, if I run select * from v$session; directly I get a schemaname of SCHEMA_A which is what I'm after, whereas in the code I have supplied, the outcome is always SYS.

Can anyone advise please where I have gone wrong and how I can fix this?

Thanks

Sean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't done anything wrong. `v$session.schemaname` changes to the owner of the currently running code, so it's expected that inside your procedure, you would capture the procedure owner rather than the initiating user. For this reason, this particular column is not useful in an auditing situation like this. It would only be useful if you had something asynchronousy polling `v$session` from outside the session, which is not the case with a system trigger.

This shouldn't be a problem, however, as you can simply ignore it and use `v$session.username` or one of the various other `USERENV` options.